# Setting grails proxy username with special \ character causes error

Tags: grails

Our firm uses a corporate proxy with a username in the following form `domainName\username` . When I try to add the proxy from command line using `add-proxy` command.

The exception I get is:

```
Error WARNING: Error configuring proxy settings: startup failed:
C:\Documents and Settings\username\.grails\ProxySettings.groovy: 1: unexpected cha
r: '\' @ line 1, column 94.
   8080", "http.proxyUser":"company\username"
```

What is the workaround for this? I tried manually editing the ProxySettings.groovy file, but same error is thrown on startup.

**[UPDATE]** I tried with Grails 2.0.0 RC3 but still unable to connect.

Comment: have you tried to escape the back slash using '\\'?

Comment: I tried \\, \\\ within single and double quotes etc. Did not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have ran into a grails bug, when domain is used in the proxy configuration: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7387. The work-around is to configure the proxy within the `BuildConfig.groovy` (kind of manually). Add the following to the existing `company\username`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "host");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port");
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("company\\username","password".toCharArray());
        }
    }); 

    [rest of code]
}
```

This way there shouldn't be problems with the backslash.

Comment: I did this change and removed the entry from proxySettings file. However I am still unable to connect(I was trying to install quartz plugin). Is there some command to check net connectivity with grails? Also, do I need to do "set proxy" anywhere?

Comment: try: `grails install-plugin http://cloud.github.com/downloads/nebolsin/grails-quartz/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip -global`

Comment: Still no luck...D:\mongo\bm>grails install-plugin http://cloud.github.com/downloads/nebolsin/gra
ils-quartz/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip -global
| Downloading zip http://cloud.github.com/downloads/nebolsin/grails-quartz/grail
| Downloading zip http://cloud.github.com/downloads/nebolsin/grails-quartz/grail
s-quartz-0.4.2.zip. Please wait....
| Error Error downloading plugin http://cloud.github.com/downloads/nebolsin/grai
ls-quartz/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreacha
ble: connect

Comment: I tried the url in IE and our proxy blocked it. I guess your answer is right and our damn proxy is the problem.