# Grails fails at startup - Error parsing HTTP header

Tags: tomcat, grails, web-applications, http-headers

I'm trying to start a Grails app at default port 8080. 
I've got success with the same configurations at my machine, but the same don't occur when I'm at another machine.

Here's the error:

```
    2015-12-15 08:30:30,393 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG http11.Http11Processor  - Error parsing HTTP request header
    java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    2015-12-15 08:30:30,399 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG http11.Http11Protocol  - Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper@81fcf4a:Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=63470,localport=8080]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
    2015-12-15 08:30:30,400 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG threads.LimitLatch  - Counting down[http-bio-8080-exec-3] latch=2
    2015-12-15 08:31:25,152 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG session.ManagerBase  - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1450175485152 sessioncount 0
    2015-12-15 08:31:25,153 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG session.ManagerBase  - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
```

I'm sure that 8080 port is free but I guess that is some Tomcat configuration that is embbeded at Grails (because the error socket occurs at port 63470). I've tried doing some search but didn't find how to solve it

**UPDATED**

Now I guess that is something with java version. I have 1.6.0.39 and 1.7.0.51 at this machine and JAVA_HOME was pointing to 1.6 version. I've also tried to set JAVA_HOME at cmd and at Windows Environment Variables, but didn't have any success

Comment: that's a longshot won't solve your problem, but try `grails run war`

Comment: @shaydel I've just tried..no success. I've also changed "grails.project.source.level" to 1.7 at BuildConfig.groovy. Without success

Comment: did you try `grails clean-all` to wipe out all plugin data(especially tomcat), and then `grails compile`?

Comment: @shaydel "grails clean-all" I've tried. But I did as you suggested and got the same error. I've chosen another port too, without success

Comment: It seems like it doesn't open the socket at all, or forcefully closes it. this can have multiple reasons, try disabling any local firewall, re-importing the project, if you use intellij\GGTS trying running it as administrator, also intellij have configuration files of it's own, there can be a mismatch in project setting. if it doesn't work, install tomcat locally, and try deploying to it after making a war,you may check `server.xml` file in tomcat to review the configuration.

Comment: @shaydel your idea of deploying at Tomcat was the solution :) Tks

Comment: @shaydel I've changed the JAVA_HOME to java7 and didn't started jboss first. Then Grails successfully run at my machine

Comment: Actually the problem was proxy. I added proper configuration at BuildConfig.groovy as explained at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352502/setting-grails-proxy-username-with-special-character-causes-error] and the problem was solved